# Why is it necessary to add extra text when editing posts?

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

Why is adding some text necessary when editing posts on Stack Overflow when the editing can be done by removing some extra words and sentences?

[Here is a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396702/length-of-array-still-0-after-deletion) I tried to edit to remove the word "**WTF**" because I don't think it should be allowed here at this platform. So when I removed the word from it and tried to save my edit, it asked me to add some fixed number of characters, even though there was no need to add extra characters.

Comment: *"event there was no need to add extra characters."* Sure there was! The first word of the title is not capitalized, there's no need for an "Edit" callout, the word "empyt" is misspelled. etc. etc.

Comment: @CodyGray: Ok, these I missed because the word I referred to was not acceptable here acc to me, so it caught my attention. Also Why does not SO has a list of words to prevent these words. My concern is not about the editing the post but for preventing the use of this kind of words similar to the word "problem" which cannot to added in the title of the post.

Comment: So don't miss them? Look more carefully? Edit the whole post when you edit?

Comment: Basically everyone but the Stack Exchange employees thinks that a title filter blocking the word "problem" was a *terrible* idea, so it is unlikely we'll add more words to the blacklist. Furthermore, "WTF" is not really offensive. It's totally fine to edit it out, but there's no cause to block it automatically. You are *assuming* it implies a curse word; the "F" could just as easily stand for "freak" or "fudge" or some other euphemism.

Comment: Surely I will be more careful now on.

Comment: @CodyGray your glasses are apparently efficient ones ;-)